# How to convert union type to enum in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to covert union type to enum or like enum in typescript

It doesn't work out with my brain.

Thank you for reading my question.

```js
type status = 'start' | 'loading' | 'stop';

class Loading {
    static staticStatus: status;
}
Loading.staticStatus.start; // i want to use.
```

or

```js
type status = 'start' | 'loading' | 'stop';

enum statusEnum = ?????;

class Loading {
    static staticStatus = statusEnum;
}
Loading.staticStatus.start; // i want to use.
```

---

I'm sorry I didn't write my questions in detail.

```
const schema ={
 status: Joi.string()
        .required()
        .valid(
            'start',
            'loading',
            'stop',
        )
}

// type setStatusType =  'start' | 'loading' | 'stop' is like this
type setStatusType = PickType<Joi.extractType<typeof schema>, 'status'>; 

enum statusEnum = ?????;

class Loading {
    static staticStatus = statusEnum;

    public setLoading() {
    this.status = Loading.staticStatus.loading // I want to use this.
    }
}
```

so I want to covert union type to enum...

Comment: There must be union type. I'm sorry I didn't write my questions in detail.

Comment: I'm using a library that auto generates union types, not enums, but having an enum would be very useful. Solutions that say "just do it the other way" aren't especially useful.

Comment: I have the same question (autogenerated `type`s) and no answer actually address the issue.

Answer (score 35):

Not sure how you would get an `enum` from a `Union` but you can easily do the reverse if you need both.

```
enum Status {
 start,
 loading,
 stop
}

type StatusAsUnion = keyof typeof Status
```

Hopefully this was useful

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i use next

```
import { IExternal } from 'external';

enum Types = {
   FIRST = 'first',
   SECOND = 'second'
}

interface IInternal extends Pick<IExternal, 'types'> {
    types: Types
}
```

IExternal['types'] === 'first' | 'second' | 'something' | 'else';

IInternal['types'] === 'first' | 'second'; and compatible with IExternal['types']

It allow you to use types from union as enum values and give you compatible check.

Answer (score -3):

Simplest solution would be to just use a `string enum`:

```
enum Status {
    start = 'start',
    loading = 'loading',
    stop = 'stop'
}


class Loading {
    static staticStatus: Status;
}

Loading.staticStatus = Status.loading;
```

## More

[String enums](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/enums.html#string-enums)

Comment: Yea, except once you decide you're going to use an enum, you're stuck with referencing that enum everywhere.
e.g. `Loading.staticStatus = 'loading'` will result in a type check error.